# How can we see the full history in the log view of an OMNeT++ simulation

Tags: omnet++, inet

Using the INET framework, if I run a simulation for a large sim-time-limit (for example, 25000s), only the partial history is visible in the log view. It says earlier entries have already been discarded.

Is there any way to see the full history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your simulation starts, go to `File` | `Preferences` | `Logs` and try to change values in `Overall hitory size` as well as `Scrollback buffer`.

[image]